# How to copy picklist value to another picklist using wokrflow or process builder?

Tags: workflow, picklist, process-builder, summer-15

I'm trying to copy picklist value from related record to another picklist and I tried both, workflow and process builder and I get stuck due to limitations of using a formula for picklists. [Here](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000Bpd7AAC) they say they fixed it in Summer '15 but I can't make it work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm sure you've probably figured this out by now since it's been 4 months.
Updating Picklist B with Picklist A's value is not possible with a WF field update.
Using process builder, you can set Picklist B with Picklist A's value by selecting "formula". Make sure to include the TEXT() function in your formula and it will work!

Check out this screen shot of "real-life" example:

[image: Process Builder Screen Shot]

Answer (score 0):

Additionally you can perform this action using the "Reference" selection when selecting the value to update with. Then select the object and picklist which you want to use to update your original picklist.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you illustrated it with an image of how to do that in Flow. [answer]

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck with same requirement. Can you please help me out with more description or screenshot.
Actually I have two dependent picklist(Controlling and Child). I want another two same dependent picklist with same values with older one.